# Decode output of Bertweet transformer

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

This is the example code from huggingface documentation on BERTweet that i try to understand

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer


bertweet = AutoModel.from_pretrained("vinai/bertweet-base")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vinai/bertweet-base", use_fast=False)

line = "SC has first two presumptive cases of coronavirus , DHEC confirms HTTPURL via @USER"
input_ids = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(line)])

with torch.no_grad():
    features = bertweet(input_ids)
```

It's not clear whether it's unsupervised or supervised learning either

I'm not even fimiliar with neural networks and transformers, but i try to use pretrained advanced methods for my topic modeling problem where traditional ML fails

features, model's output type is **transformers.modeling_outputs.BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions**

i read documentation on this class and it's not clear to me what to do with this information and how to make it readable, what am i seeing?

Does it return information about present topics in a given text? If so how to get that information?

Essentialy i'm looking for something like [this](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/api/bertopic.html#bertopic._bertopic.BERTopic.fit_transform), doc - topic tuples